Could not connect to node server on AWS EC2 instance
Deployed react node js application to AWS EC2 instance. Form is loading without any issues. But getting "Connection Timed Out" error, even after replacing localhost with EC2 instance IP address and port in axios.post. Any help is appreciated. Thank You!
When submitted react form, node js should save the infromation in MySQl database.

So you're saying that problem is between the web frontend (running on your own computer) and the EC2 backend? What is the configuration of the Security Group's Inbound Rules for that EC2 instance? What port is the backend listening on?
